# Yet another ASP.Net WebAPI route not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, breeze

First off I have read as many articles as I can find on this topic and installed several "route debug" plugins. I am more familiar with Java/Spring so I really have no idea how to debug this thing, using vs 2012. (I cannot anyway to make IISExpress print any debug much less the kind of the debug output I am used to with Spring/Tomcat.)

```
public class RouteConfig
{
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");  

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Legal", 
          action = "Index", 
          id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
  }
}
```

Now, I am able to hit the Index page via the default controller. However, I am trying to hit the URL /WebApi/Metadata/ based on the following controller:

```
[BreezeController]
public class WebApiController : ApiController {
  private readonly EFContextProvider<BankruptcyDbContext> _contextProvider =
    new EFContextProvider<BankruptcyDbContext>();

  [HttpGet]
  public string Metadata() {
    return _contextProvider.Metadata();
  }
}
```

The "Route Debugger" says that my requests for /WebApi/Metadata, /WebApi/Metadata/, /WebApi/Metadata/0, and more should "match" but all I get is 404.

Edit1: I finally found the trace logs and got a little more detail:

```
The controller for path &amp;#39;/WebApi/Metadata&amp;#39; was not found or does not implement IController
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure you are using the current latest version of Visual Studio 2012 with **Update 2** etc..
You should not only have a **RouteConfig.cs** file in **App_Start**, but also there is a **WebApiConfig.cs** file

So While Normal MVC routes use the RouteConfig class

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The Web API is using the WebApiConfig , which is stubbed out with the out of the box code suggested above in the static class  WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to register routes using the `MapHttpRoute` extension for ApiController based routes. Example:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

BTW, what is BreezeController and why is it decorated on WebApiController?

Comment: Awesome, that worked! I didn't know there was a different between mapRoute and MapHttpRoute.

Comment: @BrockNoland  Welcome to the confusing world of ASP.NET Web API vs ASP.NET MVC.  Two completely different frameworks, packaged together and made to look extremely similar "to ease the learning curve".

Comment: @Kiran - The `[BreezeController]` attribute configures the formatter and supplements the OData IQueryable processing for Breeze clients.